# Не корректное отображение сайта в результатах поисковой выдачи Yandex

Tags: php, яндекс-поиск

Уважаемые коллеги, в результатах поисковой выдачи яндекс выводит не корректное описание, в первые такое вижу, сам являюсь специалистом, но объяснить такое поведение робота яндекса не могу.
Поэтому обращаюсь к Вам, может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ситуацией.

[Адрес сайта](http://antex-dom.ru)

Если вбить адрес сайта в строку поиска яндекса, то в результатах поисковой выдачи вместо описания выводятся фрагменты php-кода, хотя сам сайт при этом открывается нормально и проблем с сайтом не наблюдалось длительное время.

В других поисковых системах все нормально, т.е. врядли проблема в web сервере.

Спасибо за внимание и надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: Быть может, ваша страница закешировалась роботом, когда она была еще "не совсем готова" (die, echo на странице) к продакшену, но уже была в интернетах?

Еще в сохраненной копии яндекса лежит такая ваша страница:
http://hghltd.yandex.net/yandbtm?fmode=inject&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.antex-dom.ru%2F&tld=by&lang=en&la=&text=http%3A%2F%2Fantex-dom.ru&l10n=ru&mime=text&sign=25e5d754da99cae439990df30e5eda2f&keyno=0

Comment: прикольно :)

Comment: Ну и при чём тут php ?

Comment: так что мне делать?
три недели назад тех.поддержка яндекса ответила, что после 1-2 обновлений поисковой базы все станет на свои места, но этого не произошло. тех.поддержка яндекса намекает на проблему с web сервером, но ведь в других поисковиках все в порядке и сам сайт всегда открывался корректно.

Comment: Я бы тоже посоветовал ждать. Видимо, обновления не так часты, либо до вашего сайта еще робот не дошел

Answer (score 1):

Видимо на момент индексирования сайта яндексом веб-сервер работал некорректно и отдавал php файлы как файлы, а не выполнял как скрипты. Кажется в некоторых конфигурациях веб-серверов такое может происходить при сбоях в работе php. По хорошему нужно проверить не был-ли это какой-то приходящий глюк который может повториться.

Ну и по возможности нужно ускорить переиндексацию сайта яндексом, добавить xml sitemap (и скормить её яндексу) например. Возможно гуглинг подскажет и какие-то другие способы.

Comment: По хорошему нужно проверить не был-ли это какой-то приходящий глюк который может повториться.
____
Очень правильное замечание. Как это можно проверить?

То что касается индексации, файл sitemap перезалил.

Не давно обнаружил, что все php файлы в кодировке UTF-8, а один из файлов был в кодировке UTF-8 BOM, из-за этого не отрабатывал ответ сервера на ошибку 404. Кодировка UTF-8 BOM добавляет какие-то там символы из-за которых не отрабатывает header 404. Получалось, что все страницы, даже не существующие были доступны и возвращали код 200. Может ли мною описанная выше проблема связана быть с эти

Comment: Насколько корректно у меня организована главная страница, получается, что на ней стоит редирект на http://antex-dom.ru/#&panel1-1&panel2-1
И вообще, получается, что доступны страницы antex-dom.ru, antex-dom.ru/index, antex-dom.ru/# и http://antex-dom.ru/#&panel1-1&panel2-1   Это нормально?